# Microservice Messaging Choices

Tags: c#, azure, data-structures, messaging, microservices

I am new to microservices, but I'd like to know what the best way to handle communication is.
I've looked into some solutions, but like to know your opinion what todo :
My microservices are hosted on azure atm and I call them with REST services,

but...

I want that the services cannot be called from anybody except from other services as I have a facade API for external apps.

I've looked into Servicebus, Eventhubs, REST , WCF, SQL with RabbitMQ, but I have no idea what is the fastest messaging service.

I prefer speed and stability over everything ,high complexityis not a problem.

Does anybody have advice on this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I voted to close because this is not a programming question. However, have you tried a simple google search on performance comparisons among the various choices? Additionally, the items you listed are all different categories of software. What are you really looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest RabbitMQ, it's easy to get started in C#, you can use the MQTT protocol or AMQP.

If you decide to use a different broker this is quite easy to update, minimal code changes are generally needed.

Both give you a lot of functionality without a lot of code.

It's possible to test clients with various online brokers, though I wouldn't use them necessarily for production.

For C# clients have a look at

https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/

http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html

Comment: this could be a solution, but will it also be able to go serverless for instance? I really want to have the newest technologies which are insanely scalable. except that it's easy, is it the best,fastest, and most scalable?

Comment: Well you will need a broker for either messaging solution, and you will likely get brokers that will handle large volumes of messages. You don't necessarily need to host the broker. MQTT in particular does scale very well, you can have very large numbers of clients and messages.